# database not updated by a task running in celery beat

Tags: django, django-celery, celerybeat

Hello I have a celery task that is suppose to run every 1 hour to fetch a key and it runs and even acts like it has updates the database but it does not update in reality

```
@app.task
def refresh_token():
    r = requests.get(AUTH_URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
    obj = json.loads(r.text)
    obj['expires_in'] = int(obj['expires_in'])
    try:
        mpesa_token = MpesaAccessToken.objects.get(id=1)
        mpesa_token.access_token = obj['access_token']
        mpesa_token.save()
        print(obj)
        print(mpesa_token.access_token)
        print("saved")
    except:
        print(obj)
        mpesa_token = MpesaAccessToken.objects.create(**obj)

    return 1
```

the last thee prints all shows in the logs but checking the admin panel, the values are not updated however when I use a view and make a request then call the function, the database get updated, could anyone know what is going on

Comment: check if your transaction has somehow made autocommit as False

Comment: the only decorator I have is that for @app.task or how else could that be done

Comment: check if your celery decorator is submitting atomic requests and your celery task is getting terminated after the execution

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `transaction.atomic()` to your code. Like this:

```
from django.db import transaction

@app.task
def refresh_token():
    with transaction.atomic():
        r = requests.get(AUTH_URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
        obj = json.loads(r.text)
        obj['expires_in'] = int(obj['expires_in'])
        try:
            mpesa_token = MpesaAccessToken.objects.get(id=1)
            mpesa_token.access_token = obj['access_token']
            mpesa_token.save()
            print(obj)
            print(mpesa_token.access_token)
            print("saved")
        except:
            print(obj)
            mpesa_token = MpesaAccessToken.objects.create(**obj)
    
        return 1
```